# Setting up external HDD to be accessable from Android device

Tags: android, external-hdd, remote-access

I am a brand new Ubuntu user on 12.04 and am trying to figure out how to set it up so that I can access my external from my android device from any location. I use the external for all my media and would like to be able to either stream or download to my Android no matter where the location.

Keep in mind that I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu, but at the same time computer know-how isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Plex media server? I use this to stream to my devices, and find it works very well

Comment: Trying to use Plex but it doesn't seem to be working right.

Comment: What issues do you seem to be running into? Mine works very well. Of you haven't created and/added a Plex account I would do that, this will make it much easier to access outside the network.